# Is it a sin to organize liqour & meat on cutomer request as a prt of my job?

Tags: karma, lay-buddhism, modern-world

I'm interested in Event planning & if I take up that job I'll have to make necessary arrangements for liqour & meat to be served at events upon client request.

I'd like to know if that is considered as a sin according to Buddhism?

Thank you,
May the nobel triple gem bless you!

Comment: For Buddhism there is no sin, only ignorance. The issues would be karma, self-respect and the maintenance of the precepts. I'm not sure it would be possible to give a straight answer because so much depends on personal circumstances. it may not be exactly 'right livelihood' but these are hard to find nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Karma is a state of mind. If you intentionally order animals to be slaughtered, it breaks the first precept. If you order meat(dead animal bodies), it does not break the first precept. Serving liquor to clients does not break the fifth precept.

But both serving liquor and selling meat can come under Micca Ajiva(wrong livelihood)as you are doing it to make a living.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's the exact point I wanted to clarify.

Comment: You're welcome!